# Angular Electron - Print to PDF works in development but not production

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, electron-packager

I am developing an Angular-Electron application where I am using electron's [printToPDF](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprinttopdfoptions) function which works for development. I am using IPC for printing to PDF.

`main.ts`

```
const electron = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs');
const ipc = electron.ipcMain;
const shell = electron.shell;

ipc.handle('print-to-pdf', async (event)=> {
  console.log('called Print to PDF');
  let date = new Date().toISOString();
  var filePDFName = 'pdf_export' + date + '.pdf';
  var DonwloadsPath = path.resolve(app.getPath("downloads"), (filePDFName));

  const pdfPath = path.join(DonwloadsPath, '');
  const win = BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(event.sender);

  console.log('window contents received');

  win.webContents.printToPDF({}).then(data => {
    fs.writeFile(pdfPath, data, err => {
      if (err) return console.log(err.message);
      shell.openExternal('file://' + pdfPath);
      event.sender.send('write-pdf-complete', pdfPath);
      console.log('PDF written');
    })
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
})
```

`home.component.ts`

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  exports: [HomeComponent],
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  providers: [],
})
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    saveToPDF() {
       console.log('button clickied')
       ipc.on('write-pdf-complete', (event, path) => {
          console.log('pdf writing complete');
       })
    }
}

ngOnInit(){
    var printPDFButton = document.getElementById('print-pdf');
    printPDFButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
       console.log('click event triggered');
       ipc.invoke('print-to-pdf');
    });
}
```

`home.component.html`

```
<button id='print-pdf' (click)="saveToPDF()">Save to PDF</button>
```

This works perfectly in development where I get the PDF ready to be saved. But when I create an exe using [electron packager](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager) and in the exe when I click on the button, [ipcMain.handle](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener) is not called at all. Just to be sure, I also tried using [ipcMain.on](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener) but same problem arises. Is the `main.ts` called in a different way for electron's exe? Please suggest something.